# "NetworkStartPosition" object like in photon truesync

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

Is there some transform object similar to "NetworkStartPosition" that works for Photon?

What I want is to set an initial spawn position for my playerPrefab, so Photon will automatically spawn the player in this position at scene start.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default implementation of a NetworkStartPosition for Photon TrueSync yet.

You can easily create custom spawn points, though. Basically reference a list of game objects in the scene (spawn positions), and move each instantiated player prefab to one of them, based on photon's playerID (TrueSync's owner.ID variable).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fixed it